# Are self loops allowed in Markov networks?

Tags: markov-random-field

I am studying about Markov networks from *[Probabilistic Graphical Models: Principles and Techniques Book by Daphne Koller and Nir Friedman](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/probabilistic-graphical-models)*.

In Bayesian networks, it is clear that, it is a directed acyclic graph and hence self loops are not allowed. But what about Markov network? Does they allow self loops?

Comment: The first paragraph and first illustration of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field) clearly answer your question.

Comment: But what do you mean by self-loops? A variable is dependent on itself? Could you please provide an example?